# How to disable Export to CSV in Azure Data Explorer (ADX)

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

I want to disable the feature Export to csv in ADX. Anybody can query on data but they should not have access to download the data

Answer (score 1):

The data can be queried in ADX from multiple tools, and various APIs (REST + SQL endpoint).
There is no good way to block saving it in CSV (or any other format) without blocking access to the data itself.